# What is the difference between scissors and shears?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, vocabulary

I never saw this word "shears", but I found it on the internet and I went to search the meaning of that. Well, if scissors and shears have the same meaning. Let me know how to use each one.

Comment: I would call the tool you use in one hand _scissors_ and the two-handed garden implement _shears_. However, I believe that technically any device with two opposing blades is a pair of shears, and some one-handed ones are called shears by specialists, e.g. a dressmaker's _pinking shears_.

Comment: Similarly there is a type of small [garden tool](http://www.oldgardentools.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/catablog/thumbnails/Grass%20Shears%20%20J-2.jpg) made from a single piece of bent metal and operated with one hand, called "edging shears".

Comment: There might be a technical distinction, but for broad usage, "scissors" is the more widely used term. "Shears" tends to be used for more specific kind of scissors, within certain hobbies/professions.

Comment: pinking shears have saw-toothed blades, and are a specialty sewing tool.

Answer (score 23):

The technical distinctions the other answers are giving might be true, but for the purpose of an English language learner, I think the most important distinction is that **scissors is a [very widely used term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scissors)**, and **shears is a [more specific, more technical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shears#Cutting_devices)**.

You're also more likely to hear "shears" with a clarifying adjective, like "[pinking shears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinking_shears)" or "[trauma shears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trauma_shears)".

In other words, most people are going to call anything with two pivoting blades "scissors", it is only within certain professions/hobbies (hair styling, sewing, crafting), that they bother to distinguish between different *types* of scissors, shears, or [snips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snips).

In sewing, for example, [you might have specialized scissors like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scissors#Sewing_and_clothes-making) crafting scissors, pinking shears, embroidery snips, dress-making shears, or tailor's scissors.

Comment: dressmaking scissors, usually.

Comment: The scissors I use in the kitchen, I've heard called "Kitchen Shears". They are fairly heavy, enough to cut through chicken to get the backbone out.

Comment: Yes, this answer is very good, but I think **kitchen shears** is the one exception that should be added, since it is reasonably common.  For example, I've never heard the term "kitchen scissors" used instead.

Answer (score 14):

Scissors and shears are essentially the same type of object - that of two sharp opposing blades with some sort of hinge mechanism.

> [Scissors](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scissors) ***usually***<sup>(1)</sup> refer to the [hand held size implements of this type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scissors), with a hole on each handle - one for the thumb one for the finger(s).

It's important to note that the holes are not necessarily the same size or shape. This depends on the ergonomic design of the scissors.

You can get [left hand and right handed scissors](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-51c5d8e8801eb83d67a73dfcd7b541b0) where the blades are arranged so that you can see the surface of what you are cutting on top of the 'inner' cutting edge. (sometimes also with grooved holes to make holding them more comfortable)

[image]

Usually (there are probably exceptions the holes are for thumb and one finger (eg for nail scissors), others can have a thumb hold and a longer loop for all four fingers opposite (paper scissors), and some have long loops on both handles so they can be operated either way round.

> [Shears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shears) ***usually***<sup>(1)</sup> refer to [larger specimens of these implements](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shears), but without the thumb/finger holes

[image]

You would grip each handle with a whole hand

> ***Not a hard and fast rule!***

There are obviously some exceptions here - particular sheep shears, which are hand held (among many other examples)

[image]

Sometimes the terms are used interchangeably - particularly I've heard [kitchen scissors also being called kitchen shears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scissors#Food_and_drug)

Also note: I am quoting a UK dictionary, so there is probably some variation in location here too.

Edit:
*Although I have just had a thought that maybe it's the cutting angle?
Scissors cut through something (paper, card, the end/middle of hair, Shears to cut something perpendicular to a surface (so to cut wool away from a sheep's skin, to shear your hair close to your head)?*

(1) At least here in the UK this seems to be the case - mileage may vary

Comment: Yes,this is the general notion and I have supplied pictures for this answer.

Comment: The disambiguation page you've linked to for "shears" calls most shears there "scissors". The article on scissors says: "Hair-cutting shears and kitchen shears are functionally equivalent to scissors, but **the larger implements tend to be called shears**" (emphasis mine). So it appears to be that scissors are generally smaller and cut through thinner material than shears.

Comment: "some sort of hinge mechanism" - that's the difference. Snips: both blades provide a 'die' against with which to cut. Shears: one of the 'blades' is a die (because *real* 'shears' imo have a spring hinge handle, as opposed to hinge pin in the middle. Or like in garden tools: one blade and one die. Ergonomics will soon teach you that to use a shear you bring the blade down to the die; that's *shearing*). Scissors: both blades cut.

Comment: To add to the confusion, giant two-handed scissor for cutting grass in places a lawnmower won't get to (30-40cm blade length) are always called shears. I have a smaller one handed version called "one-handed edging shears"

Comment: @Mazura most garden shears (in the UK, used for grass and light hedge-trimming) have bypass blades; *secateurs* for cutting stems/twigs/thin branches may be "bypass" or "anvil" (=die) and are also sometimes called "pruning shears"

Comment: The distinction between left- and right-handed scissors is nothing to do with the shape of the holes, or whether the holes are grooved.  It's to do with which blade is on top at the pivot point.  If you try to use right-handed scissors with your left hand (or vice versa), the pressure of your hand tends to push the two blades apart, whereas you want to push them together.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica You are completely correct, and I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 10):

Merriam-Webster:

shear noun
Definition of shear (Entry 2 of 2)
1a(1): a cutting implement **similar or identical** to a pair of scissors **but typically larger —usually used in plural**
(2): one blade of a pair of shears
b: any of various cutting tools or machines operating by the action of opposed cutting edges of metal —usually used in plural

Please see the pictures below.

In non-technical terms, shears are usually for cutting hedges or bushes or plants and **require two hands when used** and they look like this:

[image]

And scissors are like this and **are used with one hand:**

[image: wikipedia picture]

Comment: Other answers give different definitions, do you have a source to back up yours?

Comment: All English speakers will confirm this.  I am merely giving basic, everyday usage here. There, are specialized shears, of course, like sheep shears, too. I posted my answer to show the difference clearly. And not details like some scissors are called shears. My answer tallies with Smock's answer.

Comment: I'm not sure "all" English speakers will confirm this, but this is certainly my understanding of the difference. Doing a Google image search for "scissors" and "shears" show mostly what I would call "scissors", and both show some images of what I would call "shears". The shears are mostly very specialised, such as pinking shears and tailor's/dressmaker's shears (all types of scissors as far as I'm concerned). Only gardening and sheep shears seem different enough to use a different word for them.

Comment: When I think of shears, I think of devices with no handles at all - the blades are held together by a circular spring that you press against to close them and cut things, followed by kevlar shears that look quite similar to regular scissors.

Comment: @nick012000  I guess you don't have or have not spent any time in a garden. shears for a garden are not "specialized" at all.

Comment: Lambie, please don't speak on behalf of "all English speakers".  I speak English and I do not confirm your answer at all.  For me, "shears" would most commonly be pinking shears or kitchen shears, both of which I would use with one hand.  I would refer to the garden tool in your photo as "clippers" or possibly "loppers", but not "shears".

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Well, most native English speakers are familiar with garden shears. pinking and kitchen shears are a sub-category. And those who know garden shears just call them shears in everyday parlance. I am sorry but I'm sticking with my idea. I guess you are young and live in a city. Any suburban dweller will confirm this. In fact, it surprises me you don't know the term.

Comment: And I suspect that when you say "most native English speakers", you actually mean just those who live in your area.  And for what it's worth, I (like my grandson) have lived in the suburbs my entire life.  So guess again.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica No, I mean English speakers in Canada, the US, and the UK, Australia, New Zealand, among others. Actually, garden shears are also known as pruning shears.

Comment: All I'm asking is that you don't presume to speak on behalf of "all English speakers".  Or even "all native English speakers", or "all English speakers from USA, UK, Canada, Australia and New Zealand".  You do not represent us all.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica No, most English speakers does not refer to those in "my area". I even conceded that. And I am not willing to go further. I guess you don't visit Loews or the Home Depot, or other stores like those in other countries, that sell all types of (pruning and/or garden) shears.

Comment: "All English speakers will confirm this."  **No!**  From my experience, "shears" are kitchen shears, and those big things you use to cut bushes are *definitely not* shears, they are clippers or maybe something else depending on context.  Your comment is incredibly presumptuous and unhelpful.

Comment: The statement "All English speakers will confirm this" is almost almost almost **always wrong**.  All English speakers can't even confirm when to put an apostrophe in "its".

Comment: One more note while I'm here, because the mix of presumptuousness and condescension is really unconstructive.  You wrote: "I guess you are young and live in a city. Any suburban dweller will confirm this."  1) I am not young. 2) I do not live in a city. 3) I grew up in a very rural area gardening, cutting trees, digging trenches, and all that sort of stuff.  However, my terminology completely matches that of Dawood.  People who use different terminology from you are not automatically inferior.

Comment: @ApollyssupportsMonica Oh, we've moved now to "people who use different terminology from you are not automatically inferior". I said: All English speakers will confirm this. I am merely giving **basic, everyday usage** here. In other words, they will confirm this is just a baseline. It is not the truth. It is not every single usage of shears and scissors. It is not secaturs (a kind of pruning shear) or sheep shears etc.

Comment: Why are you still sticking to your statement that has clearly been proven to be false already?  English speakers have posted telling you they do not confirm this.  Therefore, your statement is wrong.  There is no more defense of that statement to be had.

Answer (score 1):

"Scissors" is more likely used when the blades are long compared to the handles, and are used to cut through thin things, like paper.  (Long blades relative to handle mean more cutting distance.)

"Shears" is more likely used when the handles are long compared to the blades, and are used to cut through thicker things, like cardboard or branches.  (Short blades relative to handle mean more cutting force.)

Comment: shears are used to cut through cardboard??

Comment: Although nail scissors have short blades compared to the handles.

Answer (score -3):

If I were explaining the difference between **scissors** and **shears** to someone who was oblivious to the concept at all, I would say all **scissors** are **shears** but not all **shears** are **scissors**.

Let me elaborate, physical **scissors** and the word **scissors** is a less precise, less complicated version of **shears**, even in the most novice of cutting experienced persons. Now, **shears** are any two sharpened objects and smoothed on contacting sides, that ultimately cut something using some sort of pressure for example, physiologic, electrical, hydraulic, etc. Usually cutting things such as: cloth, plastic, metal, wood, etc.

In addition, most pivoting **shears(scissors)** are self sharpening(so please don't try to sharpen **scissors** or **shears**, unless you are a trained professional). Whereas hydraulic and pneumatic **shears** must be sharpened and/or replaced quite often if they are **shearing** hard materials with acute accuracy, like metal.

The best example of my premise would be used in a vernacular:

> The cliff was a **shear** drop all the way to the bottom.
>
> The **shear** encounter with the burglar left her traumatized.
>
> The new cloth that the seamstress ordered wasn't even **shear** to the touch, so she immediately sent it back.

In laymen terms **scissors** are a specific type of **shears**. Whereas **shears** have many terminological variations for its meaning, i.e. precise, close, accurate, acute, etc.

I hope this summarizes what I believe everyone is trying to say in each response, only in tidbits. I hope this puts it together in a more understandable way. I welcome all questions, comments and criticism (positive or negative), just be respectful.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing, and for being open to critique. There's a lot of information here. I would suggest organizing it in a way that helps the learner understand by separating it into logical paragraphs, formatting your examples and using informative headings. You can browse the site and find answers with high scores to see what the community expects and appreciates.

Comment: I agree with dwilli that you should organize this into paragraphs. Additionally, you have a few errors in this answer--you've confused "shear" with "sheer" in a few cases.

Comment: None of your vernacular examples are correct. Cliffs have "sheer drops" not "shear drops." Clothing is "sheer," not "shear" and this is a visible quality, not a tactile one. Neither a "shear encounter" nor a "sheer encounter" is idiomatic.

Comment: Neither scissors nor shears are "self-sharpening", and with proper tools anyone can sharpen a pair of scissors safely and effectively.  [Here](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Smith-s-Scissor-and-Knife-Sharpener/4752024?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-tol-_-google-_-lia-_-216-_-utilityknives-_-4752024-_-0&store_code=633&placeholder=null&gclid=CjwKCAiA27LvBRB0EiwAPc8XWak1urRWc1djyzwGAmw9PjyPztsvB_IkWIsd9UOfyrm8T59jxVsGpBoC2fsQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is one example - others can easily be found.

Comment: Ah, but what about a "sheer hulk"? :-) (It's an archaic shipbuilding term. It does ***not*** mean "a completely wrecked vessel" - instead, it means "a vessel equipped with sheers (a type of crane) used to install the lower masts into vessels under construction").